# What takes more memory, an 8 char string or 8 digit int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing a program that will deal with approx. 90 billion records, so I need to manage memory carefully. Which is larger in memory: 8 char string or 8 digit int?

Details:
-Python 3.7.4
-64 bits

Edit1:
following the advice of user8080blablabla I got:

```
sys.getsizeof(99999999)
28
sys.getsizeof("99999999")
57
```

seriously? a 8 char string is 57 bytes long?!?

Comment: This is likely interpreter and even version specific. Can you tell us which version of which Python interpreter you are using? It may also be relevant if it's a 32- or 64-bit build.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` should give you the answer

Comment: @Blckknght check edit! ill check user8408080

Comment: even if the answer for any of those is one byte, it's still 90 GB, what kind of computer are you using?

Comment: this will run on a very large machine... pagination will be necessary, but as little pages as needed, the better

Comment: -1 because for me it seems that this question is too broad. we don't know what kind of records you are handling; string and integer size depends on many factors: you can use python's built-in int or for example numpy dtype. also you said it should be memory efficient but then says that pagination will be necessary (here I might not understand what you mean by pagination, I guess taking data by chunks from disk?)

Comment: _I'm developing a program that will deal with approx. 90 billion records, so I need to manage memory carefully._ If you're extremely concerned with performance, then it may be worth considering another programming language. As an aside, "90 billion records" doesn't provide much information, what matters is how they're being used, how big they are, etc.

Comment: @AMC I'm not "extremely" concerned... it's just that is really easy to run out of memory and see the performance go by the drain... python+pandas+matplot is a great combo in terms of productivity though... and all of them are being used, but not all fields... right now only a date-field and this number

Comment: @Leonardo _python+pandas+matplot is a great combo in terms of productivity though_ I can't disagree with that! _I'm not "extremely" concerned... it's just that is really easy to run out of memory and see the performance go by the drain..._ Ah, you should be alright then, as long as you make good use of the performance-related options provided by Pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` will generally take less memory than its representation as a string, because it is more compact. However, because Python `int` values are objects, they still take quite a lot of space each compared to primitive values in other languages: the integer object `1` takes up 28 bytes of memory on my machine.

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
```

If minimising memory use is your priority, and there is a maximum range the integers can be in, consider using the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module. It can store numeric data (or Unicode characters) in an array, in a primitive data type of your choice, so that each value isn't an object taking up 28+ bytes.

```py
>>> from array import array
>>> arr = array('I') # unsigned int in C
>>> arr.extend(range(10000))
>>> arr.itemsize
4
>>> sys.getsizeof(arr)
40404
```

The actual number of bytes used per item is dependent on the machine architecture. On my machine, each number takes 4 bytes; there are 404 bytes of overhead for an array of length 10,000. Check `arr.itemsize` on your machine to see if you need a different primitive type; fewer than 4 bytes is not enough for an 8-digit number.

---

That said, you should not be trying to fit 90 billion numbers in memory, at 4 bytes each; this would take 360GB of memory. Look for a solution which doesn't require holding every record in memory at once.

Answer (score 2):

You ought to remember that strings are represented as [Unicodes](https://home.unicode.org/) in Python, therefore storing a digit in a string can take an upwards of 4-bytes per character to store, which is why you see such a large discrepancy between `int` and `str` ([interesting read on the topic](https://rushter.com/blog/python-strings-and-memory/)).

If you are worried about memory allocation I would instead recommend using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to manage the backend for you when it comes to manipulating large datasets.